# What's wrong with my Xen bridge configuration

Tags: debian, xen

I'm on Debian 9 (stretch):

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.9.0-3-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u5 (2017-09-19)
```

I'm trying to setup a Xen guest. I have installed Xen and now working on a Dom-0:

```
sudo xl list
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs  State   Time(s)
Domain-0                                     0  7881     4     r-----     213.2

$ sudo xl info
host                   : myserver
release                : 4.9.0-3-amd64
version                : #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u5 (2017-09-19)
machine                : x86_64
nr_cpus                : 4
max_cpu_id             : 3
nr_nodes               : 1
cores_per_socket       : 4
threads_per_core       : 1
cpu_mhz                : 3092
hw_caps                : b7ebfbff:17bae3ff:28100800:00000001:00000001:00000000:00000000:00000100
virt_caps              : hvm
total_memory           : 8103
free_memory            : 128
sharing_freed_memory   : 0
sharing_used_memory    : 0
outstanding_claims     : 0
free_cpus              : 0
xen_major              : 4
xen_minor              : 8
xen_extra              : .5
xen_version            : 4.8.5
xen_caps               : xen-3.0-x86_64 xen-3.0-x86_32p hvm-3.0-x86_32 hvm-3.0-x86_32p hvm-3.0-x86_64 
xen_scheduler          : credit
xen_pagesize           : 4096
platform_params        : virt_start=0xffff800000000000
xen_changeset          : 
xen_commandline        : placeholder
cc_compiler            : gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
cc_compile_by          : ijackson
cc_compile_domain      : chiark.greenend.org.uk
cc_compile_date        : Fri Jan 11 18:02:57 UTC 2019
build_id               : 9a71c39470d087c0c9fa0d33c04d985ea08aaa04
xend_config_format     : 4
```

Now I'm trying to setup a bridge. I'm following the instructions in https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_Project_Beginners_Guide

My configuration file is:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto xenbr0
iface xenbr0 inet dhcp
   bridge_ports eth0
```

If I run `sudo service networking restart` it takes more than a minute.

Then the state of the bridge is strange:

```
$ sudo brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
xenbr0      8000.000000000000   no
```

The bridge has no real id and is not enabled.

I tried several different configurations for /etc/network/interfaces all of them failed.

Any ideas, why I can't setup a xen bridge?

**Edit:**
After the comment of @A.B and the answer of @user337916 I added the line `auto eth0` into my configuration

The answers to the follwoing commands are very confusing:

```
sudo brctl addif xenbr0 eth0
interface eth0 does not exist!

sudo ifup -v eth0
ifup: interface eth0 already configured
```

How is it possible, that something that *does not exist* can be *already configured*?.

Here is another output:

```
sudo ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 14:da:e9:dd:ad:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: xenbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 3a:d9:57:ac:9a:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: The output is saying it has an id. STP a bridge negotiation protocol, not the bridge per se, and if nowadays it is by default enabled, so much the better. So, I think, your question as it is does not make sense.

Comment: does eth0 actually exist? Is it the correct name?

Comment: @A.B You are right! As you can see in my comment to the answer of @user337916 the interface `eth0` does not exist.

Comment: @A.B Thanks for your hint: _eth0_ was not the correct name. They changed the naming between Debian-8 and Debian-9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Debian Network Configuration page](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration) says:

> As of Stretch, the old network names like eth0, eth1 have gone away as the device name can change. The new names are similar to these: enp6s0, enp8s0, enp0s31f6, enp5s0.

Hence I had to change `eth0`to `enp4s0`, and this fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

it looks as if you didn't add the interface to the bridge.
i.e.

```
sudo brctl addif xenbr0 eth0
```

give that a shot

Comment: I get the following answer to your  _brctl_ command: `interface eth0 does not exist!`. So the interface _eth0_ obviously does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

On my host machine the firewall (iptables) was blocking the traffic from guest machines to the Internet. Setting the following fixed the issue:

```
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

Secondly, if running Xen with brctl, I had to do:

```
brctl delif virbr0 virbr0-nic
brctl addif virbr0 enp1s0
```